# Getting this error 'name' is deprecated.ts(6385)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, deprecated

I'm working in Visual Studio Code for javascript. I'm following along in an assignment and I'm getting the error `'name' is deprecated ts(6385)`. I'm not sure why it won't run after I've declared the variable?

```
let name = 'John'
let score = 103
console.log(name)
```

I found a similar question here but that person defined their variable twice. Mine is only defined once.

Comment: What is the exact warning you're getting?

Comment: Exact error is "lib.dom.d.ts(19619, 5): The declaration was marked as deprecated here."

Comment: The marked duplicate only defines the variable once, too.  The second line is an *assignment*, but does not re-declare the variable.